# alignParentBottom not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

The Following is what I want

[image]

And following is my XML Code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="2dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    >
    <!--style="@style/sub_linearlayout_in_listview_phonedescriptiosn"-->
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <!--Header Right Pane-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_rightpane"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        >
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/divider"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_order_no"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Order # QW1233"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!--Footer Right Pane-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer_rightpane"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        >
        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider_footer_rightpane"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/divider"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_total"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Total"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/divider_footer_rightpane"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_total_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rs. 500.00"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/divider_footer_rightpane"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/divider"
            android:layout_below="@id/textview_total"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!--Mid-Content Right Pane-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/header_rightpane"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer_rightpane"
        android:padding="5dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="ListView will be here"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But its not working, I am getting the Following Output

[image]

Explanation -

There is a Left Pane and Right Pane

Inside Right Pane -> There is a "Header Relative Layout" , "Footer Relative Layout" and "Center Relative Layout" between header and footer.

Now, the "Header Relative Layout" is taking all the space till bottom as shown in an Image, but it should not take all the space till bottom

The Reason "Header Relative Layout" is taking all the space till Bottom is because of this,

```
<View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/divider"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            />
```

This View is inside "Header Relative Layout" and I am using

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

And due to this line, its taking all the space long till Bottom

If I remove the above space then I am getting the Correct Layout, But why is this Line not working over here ? I am writing this line over here, bacause I want that divider line (View) to be at the bottom of the "Header Relative Layout". This is a Requirement.

Comment: why do you set alignParentBottom to your divider??? this could be simplified easily, but main point is that divider should have layout_below with header id

Comment: the main advantage of RelativeLayout that the whole right layout could be simplified to have all your views in the single parent. You just need to make views RELATIVE - relative to parent, relative to other views

Comment: Yes @ViktorYakunin I think "layout_below" with header id would do it. But why is "layout_alignParentBottom" is not working there. It should place that divider at the bottom of "Header Relative Layout" and not at the root "Relative Layout".    I just wanted to know the issue , why is it not working there.

Comment: that might be correct, but where is the bottom of your layout? if you set a fixed height to the layout it will work. but if the heigth is wrap content, then android will wrap it to the parent bottom with align bottom

Comment: Yes @Rithe you are absolutely correct that if the height is wrap_content, then android will wrap it to the parent bottom, AND parent bottom in this case should be "header_rightpane" i.e., "Header Relative Layout" and not the root relativelayout, isn't it ?? or am I wrong ?

Comment: that's what i mean, your header right pane layout does not have a bottom set, because wrap_content does not specify a fixed bottom. so it will be aligned to its parent layout which has set match_parent.

Comment: @Rithe OK Gotta, because wrap_content does not specify a fixed bottom, so it will be aligned to its parent layout. Thanks for explaining. Thank You Very Much

Answer (score 1):

Don't use nested layouts in this part. It is not required and might cause performance problems. Just use `layout_below` and `layout_above` and you can achieve what you want:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_order_no"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Order # QW1233"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview_order_no"
    android:background="@drawable/divider" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/divider_footer_top_rightpane"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/divider"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textview_total"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_total"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Total"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/divider_footer_bottom_rightpane" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_total_value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Rs. 500.00"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/divider_footer_bottom_rightpane" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/divider_footer_bottom_rightpane"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/divider"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="ListView will be here" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that I just used a black color instead of `@drawable/divider`

[image]

Check the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) for a short explaination:

> Note that you cannot have a circular dependency between the size of
>   the RelativeLayout and the position of its children. For example, you
>   cannot have a RelativeLayout whose height is set to WRAP_CONTENT and a
>   child set to ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM.

Comment: Hey, @oberflansch Why I am using Nested Layouts is because, I want some more TextViews in "Header Relative Layout" and some in "Footer Relative Layout".    And also I may require different background color for Header and Footer in future, thats why I used this type of Layout

Comment: Yeah well. Then just set your devider below `textview_order_no` and remove `layout_alignParentBottom`.

Comment: Yes @oberflansch I think that would do it. But I just really want to know, why is "layout_alignParentBottom" is not working there. what is the problem. That's my Question. I just want to Understand it

Comment: In short, because the height of `header_rightpane ` is wrap content. So its childs are positioned are measured before its height is determined.

Comment: And alignBottom causes the Didiver to be at the bottom of the screen. So `header_rightpane ` thinks its child is that large. If you would set the height of `header_rightpane ` to a fixed size, it does not need to check its childs for they height and waht you are trying would work.

Comment: Yes @oberflansch you are right about "if I fixed the size of header_rightpane"  then, what I was trying is working. And thanks for explaining the problem, I got it a little bit what you are saying. But I thought that "alignParentBottom" is used to place at the bottom of current Layout in which it is, and not the root Layout

Answer (score 0):

i know, relative layouts have advantages, but for layouts they are just in one line, they are usually not the best solution. in this situation a linear layout will be a better solution.

try this for your header:

```
<!--Header Right Pane-->
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/header_rightpane"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:padding="5dp"
  android:gravity="center"
  >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_order_no"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Order # QW1233"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    />

  <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/divider"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hey @Rithe why I am not Using a LinearLayout as root element is because there are some more "TextViews" left or right to "textview_order_no" and also to "textview_total" & "textview_total_value"

Comment: ok, then it might make sense. here you have 2 possibilities. first is to nest your textviews in an extra layout. second would be to put all in one layout, remove the alignparentbottom property and set a below property for the divider

Comment: hmmm @Rithe I think that would do it